# Eclipse CDT: how to make it jump to errors in external files?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

I use Luna CDT. It successfully opens a file in editor when I double click on error in Console view, but only if the file is from the project. If an error looks somewhat like:

```
/usr/include/boost/any.hpp:260:15: error: cannot convert ‘UINT32* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘A*’ in return
```

clicking on it doesn't jump to /usr/include/boost/any.hpp:260:15. It is very annoying. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Does it generate an error in your „Error log“ view when you double click? I’m not sure if there’s an option but knowing if it generates an error would really help.